# distribution fitting advice

Tags: distributions, fitting

I have a set of vegetation cover samples (see histogram) that I would like to fit a distribution to so that I can generate hypothetical data on which to run power analyses with different sample sizes and shifts in the distribution. There are many zero values in this data set, which are real, and we think the value at 60% shouldn't be ignored either. So far, I've had the best luck fitting a zero inflated beta (blue line) and a power law (red line) distribution using GAMLSS, but neither is really appropriate because the zeros are not actually inflated, and the power law doesn't include zero. I've also tried a bootstrap approach, which was informative but limited in that I couldn't think of how to easily tests shifts in the distribution. I'd really appreciate any suggestions for an appropriate distribution to try fitting or alternative methods to approach this problem.
[image: histogram]

Here are the data: "0.5961,0.001,1e-04,7e-04,0,0,0.004,0.0132,0.0088,0.01,0,0,5e-04,0.0111,0,0.0077,0.0034,0,0,1e-04,0,0,0.0148,9e-04,2e-04,0,0,0,2e-04,0.0084,0,0,1e-04,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2212,0.0509,0,0,0,0.0711,0.1189,0.1535,0.0129,0.0375,0.0401,0.0048,0,0.002,0.0037,0.0485,0.0523,0.0203,2e-04,0,5e-04,4e-04,0.0103,0.002,0.0105,0.0051,2e-04,0.0011,4e-04,0.0057,0.0088,0,3e-04,0,0.0022,0.0025,0,0,0,0,0,0.0062,0,0.0019,0,0,0.0023,3e-04,0,6e-04,5e-04,0,4e-04,0,7e-04,2e-04,2e-04,7e-04,1e-04,0.0019,0.1015,0.0051,0,6e-04,0,1e-04,2e-04,0.0012,0.0032,0,0,0.0127,0.0138,5e-04,0.009,0.0069,0.0164,0.0159,0.0168,5e-04,0,0"

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "shifts in the distribution"?  A natural interpretation would a simple *translation,* whereby a distribution function $x\to F(x)$ is changed to $F\to F(x-\mu)$ (thereby "shifting" it $\mu$ units to the right), but that's not a plausible thing to contemplate in these circumstances, because the spike at zero would disappear to be replaced by a spike at $\mu.$

Comment: By shift, I meant retain the large number of zero or near zero values but increase the number of mid to extreme values and so the mean would be something closer to 7-8%. Does this seem plausible? I thought of a translation, but it has the problem you mention.

Comment: put another way, the general distribution would be the same, but the tail would be heavier

Comment: Okay.  Do you have any kind of theory, even a qualitative one; or even a body of previous experience, that would suggest what form this distribution might take?  It would also be germane to consider how sensitive your test is to variations in the distribution (and the types of those variations), because that would suggest what aspects of the distribution really matter in your problem.

Comment: From my experience, I think the general form of the distribution of the sample data accurately reflects that of the population, but we need to sample more to figure out how many more results we'll see in the 5-60% range.  I'm trying to estimate how much more we need to sample to estimate the mean under different hypothetical scenarios (different tail weights).

Comment: If you believe your zero-inflated Beta is at least sort of reasonable, you can easily adjust the tail weights by changing the Beta parameters.  Simultaneously consider adjusting the proportion of zeros -- Binomial sampling theory will tell you by how much.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful!